# compare two lists of unequal entries and get the lines containing matching elements tcl

Tags: arrays, list, match, tcl

I have two files in the format (these are columns):

```
color number day
blue   8      Monday
yellow 5      Saturday
green  0      Thursday
orange 6      Tuesday

color number day
yellow 0      Saturday
orange 6      Tuesday
```

Expected output:

```
color number day
yellow 0      Saturday   different
orange 6      Tuesday    same
```

piece of code:

```
set color [lindex $file 0]
set number [lindex $file 1]
set day [lindex $file 2] #same assignments for file2 entries
foreach line $file line1 $file2 {
append name "$color $number $day $number_file2 $day_file2 \n"
}
set final [exec column -t << name]
puts $logfile $final
```

if the color is found same in any of the line, entire line has to be printed into new file in columns. and i should be able to compare the columns with number. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives the output:

```
set f1 [open file1.txt r]
set f2 [open file2.txt r]

set data1 [read $f1]
set data2 [read $f2]

# Insert the file contents in an array file1
foreach line [split $data1 \n] {
    if {[lindex $line 0] eq "color"} {continue}
    lassign [lsearch -all -inline -not [split $line] ""] color number day
    set file1($color) [list $number $day]
}

# Insert the second file contents in an array file2
foreach line [split $data2 \n] {
    if {[lindex $line 0] eq "color"} {continue}
    lassign [lsearch -all -inline -not [split $line] ""] color number day
    set file2($color) [list $number $day]
}

set out [open output.txt w]
puts $out "color number day"

foreach {color num_day} [array get file2] {
    # If the color from file2 exists in file1...
    if {[info exists file1($color)]} {
        # Compare their numbers...
        set comparison [expr {
            [lindex $file1($color) 0] == [lindex $file2($color) 0] ? "same" : "different"
        }]
        # then print in the output file
        puts $out "$color $file2($color) $comparison"
    }
}

close $out
```

Output (the spacing and the order of the lines are not kept however, but since the lines with the same color can be anywhere in the file, I don't think it should be an issue):

```
color number day
orange 6 Tuesday same
yellow 0 Saturday different
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Jerry. How does the third foreach loop work? Since it is outside the foreach loops where our arrays are stored, its returning only one entry for me.

Comment: Is it possible to suggest a way to compare one to one index in the array of color? The entries before and after a mismatch is also getting omitted. Please suggest

Comment: @Neetu I'm not sure how to answer you because I have a feeling you are talking about something different from what I understood from your question. I have already inserted comments in my code for the 3rd foreach loop and there's not much left to explain I feel. And I don't understand what you mean by comparing the one to one index in the array of color. Arrays have unique keys so if you have one color appear multiple times in any of the files, it gets overwritten by the latest one, but your question doesn't make mention of that nor mentions how to do a comparison in that case

Comment: You said "if the color is found same in any of the line" after all.

Comment: Its clear. I had wrongly placed the puts statement outside the foreach. Other part of my code had wrong logic too. Corrected them. Works fine. Thanks.